# Upload photo from swift to django api

Tags: django, swift, image-uploading

I want to upload image from iDevice to the web server .                 I use Django API .
photo not uploaded , where is the wrong in my code please

Thank you for helping

```
var data :NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation( image!, 100.0)
let boundary = "Boundary-\(NSUUID.alloc().UUIDString)"
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let url = NSURL(string: APIURLs.uploadWorkerImage.stringByAppendingString(workerId))
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "PATCH"
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let body = NSMutableData()


    let filename = "fileName.jpeg"
    let mimetype = "image/jpeg"

    body.appendData(NSString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData(NSString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData(NSString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData(data)
    body.appendData(NSString(string: "\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    body.appendData(NSString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    request.HTTPBody = body

    let downloadTask = session?.downloadTaskWithRequest(request)
    downloadTask?.resume()
```

Edit

if i use this command the photo uploaded successfuly

```
curl -H  -X PATCH --form "photo=@static/images/close.png" http://apiurl
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything Django-related here... What's your server-side code like? What are the errors you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in data of image

```
var data :NSData =   NSData(contentsOfFile: path)!
```

instead of

```
var data :NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation( image!, 100.0)
```

I hope this help anyone

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong type. `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` is to download something. You need to use `NSURLSessionUploadTask`.

Comment: Thank you for response , I just tried session.dataTaskWithRequest and nothing happen !
how to use NSURLSessionUploadTask because it contains fromFile parameter and i use NSData to upload image

Comment: `NSURLSession` has `uploadTaskWithRequest(_:fromData:completionHandler:)` method.

Comment: I am sorry not helped me